# background_process module hogging system resource?

Tags: 7

I Ran a script using [Background Process](https://drupal.org/project/background_process) module which hogged my system resources.
I somehow managed to kill that.
Then i ran the script again with changed parameters.
My system hanged again..

I noticed that there were about 8-9 entries in background_process table .
Is it possible that they all start running as soon as background_process module is enabled ?